# Adding validation property attributes in views with Html.EditorFor() methods not inside a Html.BegingForm() method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have noticed that validation attributes are only added to the elements that were created via `Html.EditorFor(`) helper method and which are inside a `Html.BegingForm()` method, that respectively creates the "Form" tag and attributes.

Is there any way, besides manually creating the elements and attributes of course to add the required validation attributes to elements created with helper methods and which are not inside the `Html.BegingForm()` method ?

I need to validate at the client side and don't want to manually either create said attributes or script this behavior explicitly and instead take advantage of the MVC feature that adds said attributes automatically as per metadata on the model for use with the jquery-validate plugin at the client-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unobtrusive validation attributes emitted only if:

- the `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` flag is set to `true`
- the `ViewContext.FormContext` is not `null` (e.g the Html helper is executed inside a `Html.BeginForm` block)

So you can manually create a `FormContext` and assign it to `ViewContext.FormContext` before using your Html helpers:

```
@{
    ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext();
}

@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SomeProperty)
```

However you should note that with this approach you lose the from nesting feature of `Html.BeginForm` so if you want to create a new logical form you need to again create `new FormContext()` and manage the old context yourself.

Comment: In addition to this, if you are using a drop-down list in a editor template then you also need to specify "m => m" as the selector rather than "m => Model". This comment is for others who follow rather than the attention of nemesv who's excellent tip just made my day :-)